# How to use Variational Autoencoder as a Feature Extractor?

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, feature-extraction, autoencoder

I want to use my VAE trained on an image dataset as a feature extractor for another task, so that I could for example replace a ResNet for feature extraction with my VAE.
Which Layers do I use for this?

With "standard" autoencoders you just take the encoding network, but since the latent layer of the VAE consist of mean and distribution I do not know which layers I should use for feature extraction.

Does somebody know how to use a VAE as a feature extractor and what to consider with using different components?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hidden variables z are used in VAEs as the extracted features for dimensionality reduction. Here is an example dimensionality reduction from four features in the original space (`[x1,x2,x3,x4]`) to two features in the reduced space (`[z1,z2]`) ([source](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2002.10464.pdf)):

[image]

Once you have trained the model, you can pass a sample to the encoder it extracts the features. You may find a Keras implementation example on mnist data [here](https://keras.io/examples/generative/vae/) (see the `plot_label_clusters` function):
[image]